# Change numbers in excel from <5 to 5

Tags: excel

I have many data in my excel sheet and many of them are <5 (when I say <5, it literally shows <5, not 4/3/2/1). I want to convert them to a value of 5. How do I do it?

Comment: Select the entire column (click the letter at the top), use CTRL + F to open the find and replace dialogue (go to the replace tab), and replace <5 with 5? Are you asking how to do this in VB or by using formulas? Or just to correct a sheet one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+F` Click on `Replace` tab and then in `Find What` give your input as <5 and in `Replace With` give your input as 5. Click `Replace All`

Comment: Wow that actually works! And I thought I have to write some complex functions. Thanks!